# drush cr on replicated servers

Tags: drush

I am the administrator of a **Drupal site replicated on 4 servers**, behind a load balancer. There is only one database that is shared by the 4 instances. When I run **drush cr**, is it necessary to run it on each of the 4 nodes, or is it enough to run it on only one?

Comment: Are there 4 databases? Then it needs to run 4 times.

Comment: All 4 nodes point to the same database.

Comment: It depends where the cache is stored. If it's in the single shared database, running drush on one server is probably enough.

Comment: Where do you have to look to find out where the cache is being stored? Thanks.

Comment: As you said, all 4 nodes point to the same database. Caches are in there. So running it once is sufficient.